# importing file within seperate folder with ReactJS not working

Tags: reactjs

I am just starting a new React project but I am having trouble importing a particular file, which is located in a seperate folder named 'Components', into my app.js file.

Please have a look below at the code I am using to import.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Category from './Components/Category.js';
import './App.css';
```

And here is the barely developed Category component, if its of any use in providing a sulution?

```
const Category=()=>{
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="categories">
                <div class="category-choice">
                    <h1>CAREER</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="category-choice">
                    <h1>FINANCE</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}

export default Category;
```

And here is the error message react is providing me with 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to `import` `React` everywhere where you are using `JSX`. it is important because all `JSX` elements get transpiled to `React.createElement`. so `React` must always be in scope.

```
import React from 'react' // add this line

const Category=()=>{
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="categories">
                <div class="category-choice">
                    <h1>CAREER</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="category-choice">
                    <h1>FINANCE</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}

export default Category;
```